# How to setup Go! AOP PHP with Yii 1.1.13 to get Aspect Oriented Programming working?

Tags: php, yii, integration, aop, goaop

I am trying to setup Go! AOP Php with my Yii Framework application.

I have done the following:

1-Installed Go! AOP Php with composer by adding the following line to our composer.json.

```
    "lisachenko/go-aop-php":"0.4.*"
```

2-Added an application kernel like this

```
<?php
// app/ApplicationAspectKernel.php

require_once 'TestMonitorAspect.php';

use Aspect\TestMonitorAspect;
use Go\Core\AspectKernel;
use Go\Core\AspectContainer;

/**
 * Application Aspect Kernel
 */
class ApplicationAspectKernel extends AspectKernel
{

    /**
     * Configure an AspectContainer with advisors, aspects and pointcuts
     *
     * @param AspectContainer $container
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureAop(AspectContainer $container)
    {
        $container->registerAspect(new TestMonitorAspect());
    }
}
```

3-Added a TestMonitorAspect as well.

```
<?php
// Aspect/MonitorAspect.php

namespace Aspect;

require_once realpath(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/lisachenko/go-aop-php/src/Go/Aop/Aspect.php');

use Go\Aop\Aspect;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\FieldAccess;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\MethodInvocation;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\After;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Before;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Around;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Pointcut;

/**
 * Monitor aspect
 */
class TestMonitorAspect implements Aspect
{

    /**
     * Method that will be called before real method
     *
     * @param MethodInvocation $invocation Invocation
     * @Before("within(**)")
     */
    public function beforeMethodExecution(MethodInvocation $invocation)
    {
        \Yii::trace(__CLASS__.'AOP Hello World','system.*');
    }
}
?>
```

Since his yii-aspect github project integration example is for Yii 2.0 I did my own version of the index.php initializatio of the ApplicationAspectKernel.

What I did was I initialized the ApplicationAspectKernel on the onBeginRequest of Yii app and before running the app as follows:

```
$app = Yii::createWebApplication($env->configWeb);
$app->onBeginRequest = function($event) {
            include __DIR__ . '/protected/vendor/autoload.php'; // use composer

            include __DIR__ . '/protected/vendor/lisachenko/go-aop-php/src/Go/Core/AspectKernel.php';
            include __DIR__ . '/protected/extensions/go-aop-php/ApplicationAspectKernel.php';

// Initialize an application aspect container
            $applicationAspectKernel = ApplicationAspectKernel::getInstance();
            $applicationAspectKernel->init(array(
                'debug' => true, // use 'false' for production mode
// Cache directory
                'cacheDir' => null,
                // Include paths restricts the directories where aspects should be applied, or empty for all source files
                'includePaths' => array()
            ));
        };
$app->run();
```

We cannot get any aspect to work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Any help or guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Resources we have consulted are:

1. http://go.aopphp.com/docs/
2. https://github.com/lisachenko/go-aop-php
3. https://github.com/lisachenko/yii-aspect
4. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/aspect-oriented-programming-in-php-with-go/

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated my https://github.com/lisachenko/yii-aspect repository to use composer for installing Yii and Go! AOP frameworks together. Please, check it out.

**UPD1**: There is also one-line installer for yii-aspect project on packagist:

`composer create-project lisachenko/yii-aspect --stability=dev`

**UPD2**: Detailed manual about configuration is also available in my article [Aspect-Oriented Programming With Yii](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/09/28/aspect-oriented-programming-with-yii/)